# Extracting parameter coefficients from the summary function

Tags: r, lm

I have fitted a linear regression model:

```
   Lin <- lm(y~x, data=df)
```

When I use the `summary` function, I get some output. How do I extract the parameter coefficients from this output?

Comment: `names(Lin)` will tell you where the different information is located in the fitted model. e.g. `Lin$coefficients`

Comment: You might be looking for `coef(Lin)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few ways of getting the parameter estimates:

```
R> m = lm(y ~ x)
R> m
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     0.5821       0.0878
```

Or

```
##See ?coef for details
R> coef(m)
R> coefficients(m)
```

or

```
##m is a list. So extract as usual
##str(m)
R> m$coefficients
R> m[[1]]
```

The crucial point is that `m` is an R list that you can interrogate as usual.

The same ideas apply when you use the `summary` function:

```
R> summary(m)$coefficients[,1]
(Intercept)           x 
    0.58213     0.08781
```