# extracting only value of coeffcient from lm

Tags: r, lm

I have read some posts about extracting coefficient values from lm for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208498/extracting-parameter-coefficients-from-the-summary-function)

but I would like to have only the value of intercept and not the text. What should I do?

here you can see part of my simple code:

```
...
f<-lm(res[,1]~res[,2])
f
...
```

Comment: Try `unname(f[[1]][1])`

Comment: haha 28 seconds faster :)

Comment: Or slightly easier to remember, `unname(coef(f))`.

Comment: @RHertel that works :) could please tell me what does your code do? Why should we do that? whicht data structure has 'f'?

Comment: If you look at `c(f)` you should be able to see how to access it's properties.

Comment: The structure of `f` can be inspected with `str(f)`. This shows that `f` is a list with 12 entries. The intercept is stored as one of the two values in the first entry of the list, `f[[1]]` or, equivalently, `f$coefficients`. That first entry of the list contains two named numerical values. The command `unname()`removes the name, and by using `f$coefficients[1]` it is specified that only the first value (the intercept) should be selected. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the data from the lm function, like the coefficients, p values, etc I suggest using the broom package.

Accessing the intercept can than be done using the function `tidy`. this will return a data.frame.
Simple example:

```
library(broom)
f <- lm(speed ~ ., data = cars)
df1 <- tidy(f)

df1
         term  estimate  std.error statistic      p.value
1 (Intercept) 8.2839056 0.87438449  9.473985 1.440974e-12
2        dist 0.1655676 0.01749448  9.463990 1.489836e-12
```